# Issue with using While loop in bash script (to split a file into multiple files)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I need to read data from a file and insert into multiple files (with each file less than 3mb in size, file sizes can be different). The important thing is - records for an Agent shouldn't be split across multiple files. I am doing all of this in a While loop in a UNIX bash script.

```
Input.csv
        Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
        DWH,Agent_1234,phone1  
        NULL,NULL,phone2  
        NULL,NULL,phone3 
        DWH,Agent_5678,phone1 
        NULL,NULL,phone2 
        NULL,NULL,phone3
        DWH,Agent_9999,phone1 
        NULL,NULL,phone2 
        NULL,NULL,phone3

Desired Output -

Output1.csv (less than 3MB)
        Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
        DWH,Agent_1234,phone1  
        NULL,NULL,phone2  
        NULL,NULL,phone3

Output2.csv (less than 3MB)
        Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
        DWH,Agent_5678,phone1 
        NULL,NULL,phone2 
        NULL,NULL,phone3
        DWH,Agent_9999,phone1 
        NULL,NULL,phone2 
        NULL,NULL,phone3
```

Bash Shell Script

```
#!/bin/bash
BaseFileName=$(basename $FileName | cut -d. -f1)
Header=`head -1 $FileName`
MaxFileSize=$(( 3 * 1024 * 1024 ))

    sed 1d $FileName | 
    while read -r line
    do
        echo $line >> ${BaseFileName}_${FileSeq}.csv

        MatchCount=`echo $line | grep -c -E '^.DWH'`

        if [[ $MatchCount -eq 1 ]]
        then
            FileSizeBytes=`du -b ${BaseFileName}_${FileSeq}.csv | cut -f1`
            if [[ $FileSizeBytes -gt $MaxFileSize ]] 
            then
                #Add a header record to each file
                sed -i "1i ${Header}" ${BaseFileName}_${FileSeq}.csv
                FileSeq=$((FileSeq + 1))
            fi
        fi
    done
```

It is working almost fine except 
1) It is not splitting the records as expected (some records for an Agent are split across multiple files)
2) It is inserting header record only for the first output file.
3) Too slow, it took 3 minutes for a 10MB file. In reality I have a 3GB file.

Can somebody please suggest me where I am doing it wrong.
Is there any much better way to handle this?

Comment: **Much** better ways to handle it, yes. Using `du` here is wildly inefficient, when you could just maintain a byte counter internally.

Comment: And `echo $line` is just plain buggy. See [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) #14

Comment: Also, fix the bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ finds -- typically, as a practice before asking a question here.

Comment: (And putting `>>` on the `echo`s is inefficient -- it means you're reopening the output file every time you want to write a single line).

Comment: BTW -- to be clear, are the tabs at the front of each line literal? (If not, why do you have a wildcard in front of the `DWH` in the regex?)

Comment: BTW, do you have ksh93 available? It would be considerably faster than bash, thus allowing this to be made competitive with awk in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough attempt -- it's not as fast as a pure-`awk` solution would be, but it's much, *much* faster than what you already had:

```
#!/bin/bash

# two external parameters: input file name, and max size in bytes (default to 3MB)
InputFile=$1
MaxFileSize=${2:-$(( 3 * 1024 * 1024 ))}

BaseName=${InputFile%.*} # strip extension
Ext=${InputFile##*.}     # store extension
FileSeq=0                # start output file at sequence 0

# redirect stdin from the input file, stdout to the first output file
exec <"$InputFile" || exit
exec >"${BaseName}.${FileSeq}.${Ext}" || exit

# read the header; copy it to the first output file, and initialize CurFileSize
IFS= read -r Header || exit
printf '%s\n' "$Header" || exit
CurFileSize=$(( ${#Header} + 1 ))

# ...then loop over our inputs, and copy appropriately
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = DWH,* ]] && (( CurFileSize > MaxFileSize )); then
    (( FileSeq++ ))
    exec >"${BaseName}.${FileSeq}.${Ext}" || exit
    printf '%s\n' "$Header" || exit
    CurFileSize=$(( ${#Header} + 1 ))
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$line" || exit
  (( CurFileSize += ${#line} + 1 ))
done
```

---

Noteworthy changes:

- No external tools are called at all. No `sed`, no `basename`, no `du`, no `grep`. Any time you write `$()` or ``` `` ```, there's a very nontrivial performance cost; these constructs shouldn't be used inside a tight loop unless impossible to avoid -- and when using ksh or bash extensions to the POSIX sh standard, it's rare that they are in fact impossible to avoid.
- Redirections are invoked only when it's necessary to open a new output file. We don't use `>>"$filename"` every time we want to write a line, but instead use `exec >"$filename"` every time we need to start a new output file.
- Quotes are always used during parameter expansions except in contexts where string-splitting or globbing is explicitly suppressed by other syntax. Failure to do this can corrupt your files (replacing `*` with a list of files in the current directory, for instance; replacing tabs with spaces; etc). When in doubt, quote more.
- Using `printf '%s\n'` is better-defined by the POSIX standard than `echo` -- see [the standard definition for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section.
- We're doing error-handling explicitly. One could also use `set -e`, but there are [substantial caveats](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) to its use.

---

Test procedure and output follow:

```
$ cat >input.csv <<'EOF'
Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
DWH,Agent_1234,phone1
NULL,NULL,phone2
NULL,NULL,phone3
DWH,Agent_5678,phone1
NULL,NULL,phone2
NULL,NULL,phone3
DWH,Agent_9999,phone1
NULL,NULL,phone2
NULL,NULL,phone3
EOF

$ ./splitCSV input.csv 100  ## split at first boundary after 100 bytes

$ cat input.0.csv
Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
DWH,Agent_1234,phone1
NULL,NULL,phone2
NULL,NULL,phone3
DWH,Agent_5678,phone1
NULL,NULL,phone2
NULL,NULL,phone3

$ cat input.1.csv
Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
DWH,Agent_9999,phone1
NULL,NULL,phone2
NULL,NULL,phone3
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! for the script and valuable comments. Quick question - in reality in my input file evey agent record starts with  "DWH" how can I use this in the if condition?

Comment: Is `[[ $line = DWH,* ]]` not already adequately testing for that condition?

Comment: if I run your script as is, it is just replicating the file (instead of doing the split). My guess is it might have something to do with the double quotes around DWH in the first column. Please advise.

Comment: Oh -- it wasn't clear that the double quotes were literal; I thought you were using them to delimit the string you were asking about from the rest of your English-language text, thus that the letters `DWH` were what is/was present. In the future, please use backticks, ie. `"DWH"`, to indicate literal strings in StackOverflow text formatting. Anyhow, in that case it would be `[[ $line = '"DWH",'* ]]`

Comment: It now works like a charm. You just saved my day. Thanks a lot!!! Also your suggestions to use BashPitfalls and shellcheck.net are very helpful.

Comment: Glad to help! BTW, I forgot to include an explanation of the `echo`-to-`printf` switch in my notes originally, but have edited it in. (In short, `printf`'s behavior is much better-defined by the POSIX standard, whereas much of how `echo` behaves is left up to individual implementations... and then there are implementations, such as bash's, that outright disobey the standard by default... but then *can* also be configured to obey it, and are thus unpredictable if you don't know your shell's active configuration).